# What is the point of the remainder operand in a circular array queue

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue

I am looking into how a circular array queue is written, and a part of the enqueue method is confusing to me, specifically the part where the `back` variable becomes `(back+1) % SIZE`

```
void enqueue(char x) {
    Q[back] = x
    back = (back+1) % SIZE;
}
```

What is the point of getting the remainder?  I don't understand.
(the array is called `Q`, `int front = -1`, `int back = 0`, and `int size = 0`)

Comment: Think about what happens when add enough items to reach the end of the array. Where will the data go? Imagine if `SIZE` was non-zero

Comment: Yes: you could have written: `back = (back+1) % Q.length;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a circular queue, once the back of the queue reaches the end of the array, if you add another element, it should be added at the start of the array.

The valid indices of the array are `0` to `SIZE - 1` (assuming `SIZE == Q.length`).

Therefore, after you added an element at `Q[back == SIZE-1]`, the back of the queue should become `(back+1) % SIZE == (SIZE-1+1) % SIZE == 0`.

P.S. I'm not sure if you included the full code of the `enqueue` method. You don't seem to check whether the queue is full before adding a new element.

Comment: You are correct. Please advise OP to keep track of the number of enqueued elements. Otherwise reading the array will potentially result in a longer result than there is input.

Comment: Yes, it is accounted for in the regular code, I just decided to add a partial part of the method.  Thanks for the explanation!